# Database stopped working

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

In the program I wrote I used a Database and it worked fine, but then, without touching the code I got this error message:

> The log scan number (26:366:1) passed to log scan in database
>   'C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO
>   2010\PROJECTS\PROGRAM\PROGRAM\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF' is not valid.
>
> This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf)
>   does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during
>   replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup
>   if the problem results in a failure during startup. Could not open new
>   database 'C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO
>   2010\PROJECTS\PROGRAM\PROGRAM\APP_DATA\DATABASE.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE
>   is aborted. An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Program\Program\App_Data\database.mdf failed. A database
>   with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it
>   is located on UNC share.

I don't know why this error suddenly happened, I even tried to recreate my database but after a couple of days the error showed up again.

I've been stuck for days trying figuring this out and I couldn't do it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Did you try re-attaching the `.mdf` file??

Comment: Are you using any kind of file backup/replication util, such as DropBox, SkyDrive, GoogleDrive?

Comment: I'm not using any kind of file backup/replication util

Comment: I tried to search how to attach a database in, but for some reason I can't use the SSMS